# SQL database engine to carry with Git project

Tags: mysql, sql, git, sqlite

I'm developing a small experimental project using Node.js and MySQL. The database has about 20 tables only, with less than 100 registers on each table. I work with this project in two different environments and would like to make it easier to keep the databases updated, for both architecture and data. So I desire to replace the MySQL engine with another that better fits the requirements:

- SQL;
- Compatible with Node js;
- Easy to install/access/carry;
- Free;

I think SQLite could solve my issue, but I'm not sure how the single database file will behave when managed by git. Another option would be an online database, but I don't know any that is SQL and free.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So GIT your schema, write a initial load of data and GIT that. Whenever you clone the project all you do it run the schema create and the inital load scripts and you are done. Using ANY database

Answer (score 1):

**I guess** your application must initialize a database the first time you start it up after cloning it. That is, it must create some tables and load rows into them.

You can handle this with SQLite by saving the database file as a binary git object. That should work OK, at least until the next version of SQLite comes out and breaks database file compatibility.

But a better way is to create a SQL file to do the database initialization, and store that in git. It contains the CREATE TABLE and INSERT operations necessary to set up your  database. (If you're wise you will write that SQL code so it works on both SQLite and MySQL: you'll be able to switch database servers in the future.)

Then, when your application first runs, it opens the database software and checks whether your tables are present. If they are not, your application loads them from your SQL table.

**I guess** you also want to share information inserted into the database when the application runs in more than one place.  Obviously a shared database server is a good SQL way to do this.

Without a shared server, a good way to do this is to build some kind of "save" operation into your application. It will write out the SQL INSERT for the shared information, which you can then send to another location or commit to git.

Free public shared database servers?  Your best bet is probably to run MySQL on a free-tier virtual machine on one of the server-rental ("cloud") services. Both AWS and Azure offer free tier. And Digital Ocean costs US$5 per month for a small virtual machine.

Comment: That initialization approach surely is the best one, but I think it is too much work for a small project like that since every modification to the database must be saved into a .sql file, as well as the insertions.


The SQLite compatibility is not a concern. SQLite 3 has maintained backward compatibility since 2004.